Creating a JetBrains IDE Icon Theme
I've run into trouble figuring out how to modify icons in JetBrains IDEs (specifically, IntelliJ). I wanted to modify the Kotlin file icons to have parity with Java file icons, however, I cannot figure out how to reference the Kotlin icons and modify them. They're not in the Allicons class from IntelliJ, only the Java ones.
I've searched in repositories for other Icon plugins, but either they're all autogenerated or don't have repositories, because I can't find anything for my situation.
I've tried using an IconProvider, IconMapper, and ThemeProvider. I cannot figure out how to do it with any of these things. IconProvider and IconMapper appears to be for your own project's theme, and the ThemeProvider can only reference icons in Allicons and color UI visuals.
I was expecting it to be easy to make an icon theme with these resources, but the underlying issue is I just can't figure out how to reference it.
